# Parallel Cucumber/Watir scenarios in *Windows*

Tags: windows, cucumber, parallel-processing, watir

Any thoughts on what I can do/use to run cucumber scenarios in parallel on Windows? So far, I've tried (with the follow findings):

**WatirGrid**

Have to use Ruby threads to actually run in "parallel".
  This forces us to wrap the browser object in a thread, and therefore
  un-reachable once the thread block closes. (Can't pass Browser object
  to cucumber environment)

**Hydra:**

Need SSH (and public-key) access to remote boxes (ie. No Windows)

**Selenium Grid:**

Super heavy and can't find clear Cucumber testing path

**TestJour:**

Requires Bonjour (which isn't available for Windows)

Comment: Mind if I ask the objective of running the scenarios in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Re **Watirgrid** ...

I've since added an iterate method which can be passed a block of watir code to execute against remote browser objects. So the browser objects become reusable between steps. An updated detailed cucumber example is here:

https://github.com/90kts/watirgrid/blob/master/examples/cucumber/step_definitions/example_steps.rb

Your cuke steps end up looking like this:

```
Given /^navigate to the portal$/ do
  @grid.iterate {|browser| browser.goto "http://gridinit.com/examples/logon.html" }
end

When /^they enter their credentials$/ do
  @grid.iterate do |browser|
    browser.text_field(:name => "email").set "tim@mahenterprize.com"
    browser.text_field(:name => "password").set "mahsecretz"
    browser.button(:type => "submit").click
  end
end

Then /^they should see their account settings$/ do
  @grid.iterate do |browser|
    browser.text.should =~ /Maybe I should get a real Gridinit account/
  end
end
```

If you have any questions feel free to drop me a line. We also have a commercial implementation of watirgrid on EC2 available for beta at http://gridinit.com/public/examples so stay tuned for more updates with different test frameworks!

FYI the control / iterate helpers are in the latest version of watirgrid v1.1.2

Alternatively to **do it in parallel** with different scenarios on each of the providers, I would just have a support/env.rb that looks something like this:

```
require 'watirgrid'
require 'rspec/expectations';

ENV["GRID"] = 'true'
ENV["controller_uri"] = "druby://10.0.1.3:11235"

if ENV["GRID"] then
  params = {}
  params[:controller_uri]   = ENV["controller_uri"]
  params[:browser]          = 'chrome' # type of webdriver browser to spawn
  grid ||= Watir::Grid.new(params)
  grid.start(:initiate => true, :quantity => 1, :take_all => true)
else
  @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end

Before do |scenario|
  @browser = grid.providers.first
end

at_exit do
  grid.iterate do |browser|
    browser.close
  end
  grid.release_tuples
end
```

Note I'm using `:take_all => true` to get exclusive access to a provider and releasing it back to the grid `at_exit` ... I would then call my scenarios from a separate test runner using the CLI, maybe wrapped in a bash or DOS script e.g.

```
cucumber features --name "Name of scenario 1"
cucumber features --name "Name of scenario 2"
cucumber features --name "Name of scenario 3"
...
etc
```

Comment: Wow, Open Source is just too awesome. Thanks Tim, I'll check into this today and report back. :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something? If I fire up, say, three Providers and issue a @grid.iterate block to go to cnn.com, all three browsers go the site in succession. What I'm looking to do is run, say, three separate cucumber scenarios on three separate browsers in parallel. Is this possible?

Comment: As in 3 *different* scenarios at the same time? I'm thinking we could do something like that, either using custom hooks or the CLI that comes with cukes ... First I'd need to get an array of features/scenarios and then divide them up by number of providers and split them out to individual providers ...is that what ur thinking?

Comment: Yep, that's the thought. We have a metric ton of cucumber scenarios and we're trying to figure out how best to run through them in parallel (to save time, etc)

Comment: have a look at the edits above ... or see the source here https://github.com/90kts/watirgrid/tree/master/examples/parallel/cucumber